# How to configure Target Endpoint's containing localhost and port in apigee?

Tags: apigee

I have created a very simple RESTful service and deployed it on my local tomcat server. I would like to create and configure an API proxy and test it out using Apigee. While trying to creating a new API proxy it does not allow me to point me to url endpoint containing containing localhost and port information.

```
http://localhost:8080/PageNameService/ /**** DOES NOT WORK ***/
http://weather.yahooapis.com           /***** WORKS ************/
```

Does this mean that you cannot configure Target Endpoint URL's that contain localhost and ports in apigee ? Please guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apigee Edge is hosted on a 4G cloud infrastructure and would accept a backend url for which it can act as a facade and pass on the traffic processed by it. It would not be able to connect to your tomcat server with localhost:8080. You can give any globally accessible complete URL's(it can have domain names or even ip addresses with correct ports is fine.)

Answer (score 2):

I solved this need by using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/). I am able to route calls from Edge to my local machine. Absolutely love ngork! :-)

Comment: Do I have to pay anything to use it ?

Comment: I downloaded it and tried to install it on my Win 7 machine but wouldn't work.